# Can you help me in converting an array to an index while scraping more data?

Tags: ruby

I would like to grab more data from my scraper class but im getting what seems like a simple integer conversion error.

here is the code

```
def get_more_info_for_aircraft
  aircraft = gets.strip.to_i #sintrg to an integer to_i
  UsAircraft::Scraper.more_info_for_aircraft(aircraft)  
  puts "AIRCRAFT INTEL FOR #{aircraft}."
  UsAircraft::Aircraft.all.each.with_index(1) do |aircraft|
    puts "#{aircraft.contractor} - #{aircraft.service} - #{aircraft.armament} - #{aircraft.power_plant} - #{aircraft.speed} - #{aircraft.range}"
  end
end
```

and the error code

```
scraper.rb:24:in `more_info_for_aircraft': undefined method `path' for 1:Integer (NoMethodError)
```

heres the link to the git hub to see the scraper class. any help would be much appreciated.

```
https://github.com/codyalvarez/us_aircraft
```

Comment: You've shown us `get_more_info_for_aircraft` but the error is inside `more_info_for_aircraft`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is [here](https://github.com/codyalvarez/us_aircraft/blob/c028234ed033e0626ceec78c293d268971c6e571/lib/us_aircraft/scraper.rb#L24).

```
def self.more_info_for_aircraft(aircraft)
  url = "#{BASE_URL}#{aircraft.path}"
```

The error is saying that instead of passing in an instance of UsAircraft::Aircraft you've passed in the Integer 1.

That's done [here](https://github.com/codyalvarez/us_aircraft/blob/984f6c0d2980f757351b300e40e6cdfed53c618d/lib/us_aircraft/cli.rb#L51).

```
 def get_more_info_for_aircraft
    aircraft = gets.strip.to_i #sintrg to an integer to_i
    UsAircraft::Scraper.more_info_for_aircraft(aircraft)
```

It doesn't matter if you did because [UsAircraft::Aircraft](https://github.com/codyalvarez/us_aircraft/blob/c028234ed033e0626ceec78c293d268971c6e571/lib/us_aircraft/aircraft.rb) doesn't have a path method.